# Eclipse plugin for Java that automatically adds logging events

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, eclipse-plugin

I want to add a plugin to my Eclipse(Helios) which logs my function start and end. To be more precise, I'm looking for something like this.

```
TestClass {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLog("TestClass");

    public void displayHello () {
        System.out.println("Fooo");
    }
}
```

After I add the plugin and enable functional logging,Im expecting the following

```
TestClass {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLog("TestClass");
   public void displayHello () {
     logger.debug ("displayHello() - Started");
     System.out.println("Fooo");
     logger.debug ("displayHello() - Ended");
   }
 }
```

I remember using some method to obtain the same earlier but am unable to recollect the same now.Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks
Anish

Comment: (Functional programming is something else entirely.)

Comment: While perhaps not desired, see AspectJ

Comment: Not sure that I understand the why of adding the logging automatically with a plugin. If you want logging for enter/exit (and more stuff) I'd recommend d perf4j (http://perf4j.codehaus.org/). If you're using spring in your code you can use that to enable AOP around your methods.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) its supports something like this,

```
execution(* com.java.test..*.*(..))
```

which will cover all methods in all sub-packages of project. So no need to define all methods one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about Eclipse plugins, I am assuming that the places you want to log do not necessarily exist in a single plugin.  AspectJ is a good suggestion.  However, standard AspectJ or Spring AOP will not be sufficient since it is classloader based. You will need to use [Equinox Weaving](https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/weaving/).

Equinox Weaving performs load-time weaving in an OSGi-aware way.  Essentially, you create your plugins and augment your manifest files with the proper weaving configuration.